# conversion EPSG3035 to EPSG3857 Mercator or 4326 LonLat

Tags: javascript, coordinate-transformation

Working directly in JavaScript on a geojson file, I could not find any easy way to transform my coordinates from EPSG3035 to geographic (Lon,Lat). By easy I mean: not installing another software like QGIS or similar. I have tried proj4, and ol, but both failed.

I have no clue. [the OL solution is in "t.niese" answer below]

```js
let coordinates = [4035675.373507705517113, 2862363.090465864632279]; // Luxembourg
console.log(coordinates);
// a "well-known text" WKT-OGC definition from https://epsg.io/3035
const WKT3035 = `PROJCS["ETRS89 / LAEA Europe",GEOGCS["ETRS89",DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",52],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",10],PARAMETER["false_easting",4321000],PARAMETER["false_northing",3210000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3035"]]`;
// trying OpenLayers
try {
  const fromLonLat = ol.proj.getTransform("EPSG:3035", "EPSG:4326");
  coordinates = fromLonLat(coordinates);
  console.log("using ol.proj", coordinates);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
try {  // trying proj4
    coordinates = [4035675.373507705517113, 2862363.090465864632279];
    const srcProj = new proj4.Proj(WKT3035);
    proj4(srcProj).inverse(coordinates);
  console.log("using proj4", coordinates);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.8.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.7.5/proj4.js"></script>
```

Comment: You con this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774309/proj4js-transformation-2-3-3-vs-2-4-3. It worked for my project

Comment: Ok, I will have a look. I am using v2.7.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you get is because proj4 does not know the projection `EPSG:3035`

If you run `console.log(proj4.defs('EPSG:3035'))` you can see that it returns `undefined`.

```js
console.log(proj4.defs('EPSG:3035'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.8.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.7.5/proj4.js"></script>
```

If you only used `proj4` you can just define the projection using:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:3035", /* here goes the definition of that projection */);
```

Using [`proj4.defs(name, definition)`](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js#named-projections) does not return anything, it defines the projection with that name so that it can be used with that name. After you defined the projection you can use `proj4.defs(name)` to get it.

If for OpenLayer you also need to register `proj4` after that:

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:3035", /* here goes the definition of that projection */);
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
```

The definition for `proj4` should be `+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs` (Source https://epsg.io/3035)

```js
proj4.defs("EPSG:3035", '+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

let coordinates = [4035675.373507705517113, 2862363.090465864632279]; // Luxembourg
console.log(coordinates);
try {
  // trying OpenLayers
  const fromLonLat = ol.proj.getTransform("EPSG:3035", "EPSG:4326");
  console.dir(fromLonLat(coordinates));
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}

try {
  // trying proj4
  console.dir(proj4(proj4.defs('EPSG:3035'), proj4.defs('EPSG:4326'), coordinates));
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.8.1/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.7.5/proj4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent. I have missed the "register" step for OL. Great help indeed.

Comment: However the code for proj4 doesn't change the coordinates. It keeps the source value (which in that case has been already transformed).

Comment: @allezl'OM fixed that. Now both OpenLayer and proj4 work on the original coordinates and the transformed are returned.